# Why does clang generate rsqrt, if stack-protector is turned on?

Tags: c++, clang

Check out this simple code:

```
#include <cmath>

float foo(float in) {
    return sqrtf(in);
}
```

With `-ffast-math`, clang generates `sqrtss`, as it is expected. But, if I use `-fstack-protector-all` as well, it changes `sqrtss` to `rsqrtss`, as you can see at [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/T_An7j). Why?

Comment: It generates `rsqrtss` with `-ffast-math -O3` also.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528727/why-is-sse-scalar-sqrtx-slower-than-rsqrtx-x?

Comment: @TypeIA: that is more-or-less understandable. I just don't get it, what does stack-protection has to do with sqrt.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I think you're right, I was just about to post that link myself. It makes sense that `-ffast-math -O3` would select the optimization. I guess the question is really why `-ffast-math -fstack-protector-all` does too.

Comment: Probably one of the heuristic inside LLVM...

Answer (score -1):

## The short and sweet:

`rsqrtss` is **safer** and, as a result, less accurate and slower.

`sqrtss` is **faster** and, as a result, less safe.

Why is `rsqrtss` safer?

- It doesn't use the whole XMM register.

Why is `rsqrtss` slower?

- Because it needs more registers to perform the same action as
        `sqrtss`.

Why does `rsqrtss` use a reciprocal?

- In a pinch, it seems that the reciprocal of a square root can be calculated faster and with less memory.
  Pico-spelenda: Lots of [math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root).

## The long and bitter:

### Research

- What does `-ffast-math` do?

  ```
  -ffast-math
      Enable fast-math mode. This defines the __FAST_MATH__ preprocessor
      macro, and lets the compiler make aggressive, potentially-lossy
      assumptions about floating-point math. These include:

      Floating-point math obeys regular algebraic rules for real numbers (e.g. + and * are associative, x/y == x * (1/y), and (a + b) * c == a * c + b * c),
      operands to floating-point operations are not equal to NaN and Inf, and
      +0 and -0 are interchangeable.
  ```
- What does `-fstack-protector-all` do?

  - This answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40739616/9509637).
  - Basically, it "forces the usage of stack protectors for all functions".
- **What is a "stack protector"**?

  - A nice article for [you](http://www.productive-cpp.com/hardening-cpp-programs-stack-protector/).
  - The blissfully short, quite terribly succient sparknotes is:

    - A "stack protector" is used to prevent exploitation of stack overwrites.
      the stack protector as implemented in gcc and clang adds an additional guard
      variable to each function’s stack area.
  - ***Interesting Drawback To Note:***

    "Adding these checks will lead to a little runtime overhead: More stack
    space is needed, but that is negligible except for really constrained
    systems...Do you aim for maximum security at the cost of
    performance? `-fstack-protector-all` is for you."
- **What is `sqrtss`**?

  According to @godbolt:

  ```
      Computes the square root of the low single-precision floating-point value
      in the second source operand and stores the single-precision floating-point
      result in the destination operand. The second source operand can be an XMM
      register or a 32-bit memory location. The first source and destination
      operands is an XMM register.
  ```
- **What is a "source operand"**?

  - A tutorial can be found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_addressing_modes.htm)
  - In essence, an operand is a location of data in a computer. Imagine the simple instruction of x+x=y.You need to know what 'x' is, which is the source operand. And where the result will be stored, 'y', which is the destination operand. Notice how the '+' symbol, which is commonly called an 'operation' can be forgotten, because it doesn't matter in this example.
- **What is an "XMM register"**?

  - An explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44299695/9509637).
  - It's just a specific type of register. It's primarily used in floating math
    ( which, surpisingly enough, is the math you are trying to do ).
- **What is `rsqrtss`**?

  - Again, according to @godbolt:

    ```
    Computes an approximate reciprocal of the square root of the low
    single-precision floating-point value in the source operand (second operand)
    stores the single-precision floating-point result in the destination operand.
    The source operand can be an XMM register or a 32-bit memory location. The
    destination operand is an XMM register. The three high-order doublewords of
    the destination operand remain unchanged. See Figure 10-6 in the Intel® 64 and
    IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 1, for an illustration
    of a scalar single-precision floating-point operation.
    ```
- **What is a "doubleword"?**

  - A simple [definition](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/d/doublew.htm).
  - It is a unit of measurement of computer memory, just like 'bit' or 'byte'. However, unlike 'bit' or 'byte', it is not universal and depends on the architectures of the computer.
- **What does "Figure 10-6 in the Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 1" look like?**

  - Here you [go](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.pdf).

---

**Disclaimer**: 
Most of this knowlegde comes from outside sources. I literally install clang just now to help answer your question. I'm not an expert.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! :) You wrote a lot of things, which are "around" the subject, but the my question remains to be answered. And there are some inaccuracies in your answer as well (like the difference between `sqrtss` and `rsqrtss`).

Comment: This answer has the characteristics of `sqrtss` and `rsqrtss` mixed up.